# Principal value that involves logarithms

Tags: cauchy-principal-value

I am trying to demonstrate that the principal value **via partial fractions** of (exercise VII.6.1 from Gamelin's *Complex Analysis*)

$$
\operatorname{P.V.}\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{1-x^2}=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0}\,\left[\int_0^{1-\epsilon} \frac{dx}{1-x^2} + \int_{1+\epsilon}^\infty \frac{dx}{1-x^2}\right]=0,
$$
My problem is that the second integral involves the limit

$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\operatorname{log}\frac{1+x}{1-x} = i\pi,
$$

and therefore the integral is not zero! Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Recall that $$\int \frac1t\,dt =\log(|t|)+C$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're better off rewriting your second integral as
$$
\int_{1+\epsilon}^\infty \frac{dx}{1-x^2}=-\int_{1+\epsilon}^\infty\frac{dx}{x^2-1}.
$$
This way the denominator is always positive and you can write
$$
-\int\frac{dx}{x^2-1}=-\int\frac{dx}{2(x-1)}+\int\frac{dx}{2(x+1)}=
-\frac{1}{2}\left(\log(x-1)-\log(x+1)\right)
$$

Comment: Ok, but what's the catch if you don't take that minus sign. What should be the correct evaluation if you don't put the sign in front of the integral?

Comment: @user2820579  There is an implict absolute value when you integrate $1/x$.